# Loss of Security (Update Manager doesn't ask for a password)

Tags: 13.10, updates

Ubuntu is being updated, usually with UBUNTU BASE on a weekly basis, and has been for some time.

When the INSTALL button is pressed, the software goes thru the update process.

PROBLEM:  Ubuntu does NOT request a password to authorize the update.

Isn't this a protocol violation?  Doesn't this risk entry to viruses, trojans, and the like?

Answer (score 0):

As of a version of ubuntu updates that don't require altering the core system(kernel) don't request for a password. That is because it seems many users clicked cancel instaid of authenticate at the password window mainly because they didn't want to go through the process etc

Also the download certificates are checked before installation so no viruses can enter through the update process UNLESS a program installed doesn't sign its files with a certificate.